# Can't figure out why my JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I've been messing around with JavaScript samples and ever since I edited this one I can't figure out why it wont work. Everything looks fine to me, but here is the code (JSFiddle)

https://jsfiddle.net/en2a8c1v/1/

```
function click(e) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor='" + e.target.id + "';

}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('click', click);
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you detail the problem a bit more?

Comment: I just want to know why it won't work. I'm not sure how to elaborate on that.

Comment: You're setting the background color to the string `'" + e.target.id + "'`, which is not a valid color. You can see this easily enough by using the debugger, tracing through your code, examining variables and DOM elements, as well as using the style inspector.  BTW, please put your code in the question, not an external site.

Comment: Explain briefly what you are trying to achieve and what you think is wrong.

Comment: wouldn't `'" + e.target.id + "'` be the ID of the divs which is either blue, red, green, or yellow.

Comment: Well, I want it to change the background to whatever div you click. So when you click the blue div the background color would be blue

Comment: You should have notice the complains about how jsfiddle doesn't want styles and html tags in the html area.  But the real issue is the event DOMContentLoaded was never fired.  Probably not supported by jsfiddle renderer.

Comment: It's supported, but you need the right JS settings enabled.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that in the JS settings you have no-wrap enabled (I used no-wrap head) in the load type dropdown.

Next, you need to understand that when you call e.target.id, this is already a string variable. You are literally making the background color "e.target.id". That isn't a color.

Simply change `document.body.style.backgroundColor='" + e.target.id + "';`
 to `document.body.style.backgroundColor= e.target.id;`

I'm not going to touch on the fact that this is a terrible way to go about this as I am assuming you are just playing with event handling.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am just playing around with it but if you don't mind explaining it I would love to know the better way to do it

Comment: ID's are meant to identify a specific dom element, using them in this way is incredibly unintuitive and confusing. I would recommend instead using data attributes. Something like data-clickColor="red" on your divs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Here is a guide on how to use data attributes.



Also, to touch on what Will said above, you should not be mixing your stylesheet with your html. Put your styles in a CSS file and link it with your html. This can change with JS frameworks, but don't worry about that for now.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! I personally write CSS in a different file, however this wasn't my code. Whenever I write my own stuff I'll be sure to use data attributes instead.  I have one more question if you have time. I messed around a bit more and figured if I just copy/pasted the first function and listener I could make the other button do something different, however that didn't seem to be the case, why is that? Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/1190b617/4/

Comment: Check what event you are binding the second button to.

Also, if this answered your question, could you mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will find this usefull. Use CSS attribute: background-color:rgb(x,y,z);

You can do it on simple way, for example:

```
document.getElementById("elementID").style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+ this.red + ', ' + this.green + ', ' + this.blue + ')';
```

These r,g,b values can be, for example:

```
this.red = 0;
this.green = 255;
this.blue = 130;
```